# Wordpress - Pass Query string as slash based URL

Tags: wordpress, url, themes, url-rewriting, query-string

I am trying to pass a parameter to a wordpress page. I don't want to pass it as a query string. I would like to pass as a slash based url.

Example:

```
http://localhost/mysite/pagename?user=myname
```

into

```
http://localhost/mysite/pagename/myname
```

How can I achieve this using my `functions.php` file in wordpress custom theme?

Answer (score 20):

Going through [`rewrite_rules_array`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/rewrite_rules_array) seems unneeded - it is more for a rewrite rule kill/remove than for adding rules...

## USING `functions.php`

Using WordPress theme functions (`functions.php`), there are 2 steps to pass slash-based url as `GET` parameters to a page, after any rewrite-rule change: 
**Flush rewrite rules == re-save permalink settings in admin!**

### Step 1 - [add_rewrite_rule(...)](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule)

This might be a bit confusing, when trying to get it work, because documentation  for [**`add_rewrite_rule(...)`**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule) is not quite clear on where to target the rewrite nor how to target a page by slug... and there is just an **important** note that you need to flush rewrite rules every time you change something like that...

This works for me (WP 4.3.3)

```
add_action('init', function(){
   add_rewrite_rule( 
      '^yourPageSlug/([^/]+)([/]?)(.*)', 
      //!IMPORTANT! THIS MUST BE IN SINGLE QUOTES!:
      'index.php?pagename=yourPageSlug&user=$matches[1]', 
      'top'
   );   
});
```

Arguments/Parameters:

1. Regular expression ("regexp") to match the particular url structure
2. Rewrite template in which you should target `index.php` (if it is not an external link), because all url rewriting in WordPress comes through it

   - use `pagename` `GET` parameter set to *your page slug*
   - use placeholder `$matches[indexStartingFrom1]` for regexp match - which really
     ***is* just a placeholder! ==> *use single quotes to wrap this string!***
3. > 'top' or 'bottom'. 'top' will take precedence over WordPress's existing rules, where 'bottom' will check all other rules match first. Default: "bottom"

### Step 2 - [add `query_vars`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/query_vars)

Step above is just a targeting, not passing the variables itself...

Since WordPress would clear the `$_GET` parameters "as are" and just throw them away (because it would not find anything suitable for it), we need to *tell* the WordPress that we want to use them by adding our [**custom `query_vars`**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/query_vars).

We will still not be able to retrieve them through `$_GET` superglobal, **however,**
we will be able to get them using [**`get_query_var(...)`**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_query_var/)

We tell WordPress that we want to use those `GET` parameters by adding a **`query_vars`** filter

```
add_filter('query_vars', function( $vars ){
    $vars[] = 'pagename'; 
    $vars[] = 'user'; 
    return $vars;
});
```

### Final step:
FLUSH REWRITE RULES == RESAVE PERMALINK SETTINGS!

### Usage

Then to get value of `GET` param "user" use:

```
get_query_var( 'user' )
```

---

## USING `.htaccess`

If you can, you can also use `.htaccess` rule (*considering, `/mysite/` is your rewrite base*)

```
RewriteRule ^pagename/([^/]+)$  pagename?user=$1
```

Comment: thanks a ton for this; I've been trying to figure our for a while

Answer (score 1):

Here's a thorough tutorial that gets close: http://www.rlmseo.com/blog/passing-get-query-string-parameters-in-wordpress-url/

In short, you define some new rewrite rules, and then hook them into WordPress via `add_filter('rewrite_rules_array', 'my_rewrite_rules');`

However, following that link's example, your resulting URL would be `http://localhost/mysite/pagename/user/myname` - note that **/user/** (the name of your query variable) is still included.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply... I applied the method in the url. I could see the rewrite rules being added to wordpress by printing get_option( 'rewrite_rules' );, but when I type the url http://localhost/mysite/pagename/user/myname I get 404 page not found error. Please help.

Comment: UPDATE : It seems the code has some effect on my page. However the rewrite rule does not redirect correctly. This is what I have `add_rewrite_rule('(.*(mypage/user/(.*)?))' , 'index.php?pagename=mypage&user=$matches[1]','top');` But It redirects me to [http://example.com/mypage].

Comment: Same with me @Jack Ant